# How to Access an object created in another method

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm trying to make a method where I can view the object. How can I access the `bag1` object from the `view()` method?

```
public class ArrayBagUtilities {
    public void Create() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Size of bag 1: ");
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();
        Bag bag1 = new ArrayBag(size);
        keyboard.nextLine();
        String itemStr;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int n = i+1;
            System.out.print("Item " + n + ": ");
            itemStr = keyboard.nextLine();
            bag1.add(itemStr);
        }
    }

    public void view() {
        System.out.print(bag1);
    }
}
```

Comment: All you have to do is declare `Bag bag1;` *outside* of `Create()`: make it a *class member*, instead of a "local variable".  `public class ArrayBagUtilities {  private Bag bag1; 
    public void Create() {...} ...}`

Answer (score 2):

You can declare bag1 as attribute of your class.

```
public class ArrayBagUtilities {
    private Bag bag1;
    ....
    public void Create() {
    ....
        bag1 = new ArrayBag(size);
    ....
    }

    public void view() {
        System.out.print(bag1);
    }
}
```